# how to convert CaretEvent.getDot() to rectangular coordinates?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, caret

Actually i am trying to display the  line number and coloumn number the user is currently typing in a JTextArea . My question is how can i convert CaretEvent.getDot() to rectangular coordinates so that i can achieve this ? Or is there any other method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking to use the JTextArea method, `public Rectangle modelToView(int location)`. Actually this is a method from JTextArea's parent class, JTextComponent, and can help translate an int location in the document to the current rectangle location in the GUI itself, relative to the text component.

Comment: Thanks a ton ! That helped

Answer (score 1):

> i am trying to display the line number and coloumn number the user is currently typing in a JTextArea

Check out [Text Utilities](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/26/text-utilities/). It provides methods like:

1. `getColumnAtCaret(...)`
2. `getLineAtCaret(...)`